# Updating RubyGems alongside an existing packaged installation on Joyent

Tags: ruby, rubygems

On a Joyent accelerator I'm working with, Ruby and Rubygems were installed when the server was initially setup using [Cool Stack](http://www.sunfreeware.com/coolstack.html).

The existing version of Rubygems is version 0.9.2. When it comes to upgrading RubyGems using the 'sudo gem install rubygems-update' and 'sudo update_rubygems' commands, it results in the following error:

```
./lib/rubygems.rb:124: uninitialized constant Gem::RbConfig (NameError)
    from setup.rb:24:in `require'
    from setup.rb:24
```

Without having much success in rectifying this issue, I wanted to install a fresh version of RubyGems alongside this one. As this is a production server, I want to minimize the amount of environment changes I make on the server.

If I install a fresh version of RubyGems from source, how do I set this new installed version of RubyGems as the default version of RubyGems to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think RVM is what you're looking for: http://rvm.io/rvm/install/

And then setting one Ruby install as the default: http://rvm.io/rubies/default/

Comment: I think I would give this a try if I had a test or staging server to try this one, but I only have the production server to work with, so I'm trying minimize big changes on the server.

Comment: It's no bigger than just installing one new program. If you set it up and it works, great, if not you revert the default to 'system' and pretend like it's not even there.